# prevent internet explorer from giving the option to save/download file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a site set up so when you click a  link it plays a song. chrome has an audio player that it runs. firefox has a invisible player that it runs. but ie asks if you want to open or save the file. open is fine but save is unacceptable. so how do i fix ie? I can't find anything related to my problem on the net. nothing even close. so any thoughts, advice, tell i'm a fool and i'm doing it all wrong check this out. all much appreciated

Comment: Why is save unacceptable? There's plenty of information about how playing audio through a site is virtually unprotectable, and you're probably wasting your time... *open* actually saves the file to a temporary directory anyway.

Comment: it's not acceptable because it's supporting piracy. There has to be a way to allow a user to listen to music from a site without being able to download the song. Especially with all the anti-piracy stuff that is currently going on. The main thing is responsibility. If I allow it to be stupidly easy to pirate then I am responsible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not expose your raw data if you don't want the user to access it, instead play it through a Flash player. Keep in mind, any computer literate user will be able to download your data anyway.

Comment: yeah i am not looking for a super secure way of doing this. i just do not want to be held accountable for supporting piracy. If i leave it the way it is, i feel like i am responsible for the theft. If the end user wants to go and find a way of getting at the file and pirating it then that's on them.

Comment: The flash player would then be the option, look at how soundcloud.com functions as an example.

Comment: will do. any thoughts on the jplayer plugin? i was trying to work with that but it just was not working out.

Comment: Not really, I never really added media to any of my sites, I would suggest doing some research and then posting a new question about jplayer if you don't find the answers :)

Comment: i just found a nice tutorial for the flash player and i like the looks of that much better then what i was seeing for jplayer so i will go with that. thanks for thoughts and advice

Comment: here is the tutorial i mentioned in my last comment for future researchers. http://www.4templates.com/tutorials/embedding-audio-on-your-website-with-a-flash-audio-player/

Comment: marked as answered and when i get more rep i will vote it up too :)